# chainlink keepers

Tags: solidity, chainlink

How do you let the perform upkeep function to know which instance of p it should perform upkeep for?

```
function checkUpkeep(bytes calldata /* checkData */) external override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
    for (uint256 p = 0; p < allowedAssets.length; p++) {
        if (getPrice(p) == roundCoinMoonPrice[coinRound[allowedAssets[p]]][allowedAssets[p]]) {
            //set 
            //get price should include an option p that sets the aggregator address to the p'th asset 
            upkeepNeeded = true;
        } else {
            upkeepNeeded = false;
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can only return `upkeepNeeded` once, so whatever the last instance of upkeepNeeded is will decide that.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for the response. But What if the upkeep needed is different for every instance of p? To be a bit clear, p is the price aggregator address for various assets. Meaning, getPrice(p) should only initiate an upKeepNeeded for the asset.

Comment: you'd return the different information as part of `bytes memory performData`. All customization goes in the `performData` variable. So you're have upkeepneeded set to true, and you'd return that and the address in the `performData` variable. You'd have to encode the address to be a bytes object.

Comment: understood. Thank you for the hep sir.